# How I can get f1 score, precision and recall, on a multiclass-multioutput problem?

Tags: python, classification

I am working on a NLP multiclass-multiouput classification problem.

[image: Prediction]

Here is the output prediction and the shape is (6546, 36), it's a 36 class classification problem.

I tried to use `classification_report` to get the scores and error shows `multiclass-multioutput is not supported`.

I am wondering anyone can help with this type of problem. I just trying to get a sense how the model work and to improve the model from there.

If there is any better score can evaluate this type of problem, please let me know as well.

Thank you guys in advance.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: From [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html): “Warning At present, no metric in sklearn.metrics supports the multioutput-multiclass classification task.”

Comment: Actually, looking better your problem seems to be a multi label problem (each sample can have one or multiple labels attached). Have you tried transposing the y arrays? The correct input shape for label indicator is n_samples x n_classes. To be more of help you should provide a small reproducible code example.